# Add all arguments except first to a string

Tags: string, bash, sh, args

Trying to parse all arguments to one string but my code is only giving me errors that it can't find `i`:

```
test: line 3: =: command not found
test: line 7: [i: command not found
test: line 7: [i: command not found
test: line 7: [i: command not found
test: line 7: [i: command not found
test: line 7: [i: command not found
```

Code bellow

```
#!/bin/sh

$msg=""

for i in $@
do
if [i -gt 1]; then
    msg="$msg $i"
fi
done
```

EDIT: thx for all the help, got it to work. My final solution if anyones interested:

```
#!/bin/sh

args=""
for i in "${@:2}"
do
    args="$args $i"
done
```

Comment: The first error (`test: line 3: =: command not found`) comes from an error in the assignment of `msg`: replace line 3 with `msg=""` (no dollar, this is shell, not Perl or PHP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your *specific* error messages are showing up because:

- *assigning* to a variable is not done with the `$` character as in `$msg=""`, instead you should be using `msg=""`; and
- `[` is actually a *command,* one that should be separated from other words by white space, so that the shell doesn't think you're trying to execute some mythical `[i` command.

However, you have a couple of other problems. The first is that the value of `i` needs to be obtained with `$i`, not just `i`. Using `i` on its own will give you an error along the lines of:

```
-bash: [: i: integer expression expected
```

because `i` itself is not a numeric value.

Secondly, neither `i` nor `$i` is going to be an *index* that you can compare with 1, so your `$i -gt 1` expression will not work. The word `$i` will expand to the *value* of the argument, not its index.

---

However, if you really want to process all but the first element of your argument list, `bash` has some very C-like constructs which will make your life a lot easier:

```
for ((i = 2; i <= $#; i++)) ; do   # From two to argc inclusive.
    echo Processing ${!i}
done
```

Running that with the arguments `hello my name is pax`, will result in:

```
Processing my
Processing name
Processing is
Processing pax
```

For constructing a string containing those arguments, you could use something like:

```
msg="$2"                           # Second arg (or blank if none).
for ((i = 3; i <= $#; i++)) ; do   # Append all other args.
    msg="$msg ${!i}"
done
```

which will give you (for the same arguments as above):

```
[my name is pax]
```

Although, in that case, there's an even simpler approach which doesn't involve any (explicit) loops at all:

```
msg="${@:2}"
```

Comment: If you are using bash then why are you using `eval echo \$$i` instead of `${!i}`

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９: because, up till now, I've never known of that one, always using `eval` for indirection. Changed answer to use this "new" method, that should make my code much cleaner going forward as well :-) Cheers.

Comment: While we're at it: if you all you want to do is to concatenate all arguments (leaving the first one out), you might as well ditch all this and use this parameter expansion: `msg="${@:2}"`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need a loop for your specific output (assuming a single string is actually the correct output):

```
args="${@:2}"  # Use @ instead of * to avoid IFS-based surprises
```

However, if you plan on iterating over the arguments later, a flat string is the wrong approach. You should be using an array:

```
args=( "${@:2}" )
```

Comment: Note that `args=${*:2}` might be surprising if `IFS` has been changed… `args="${@:2}"` (with quotes) should be less surprising.

Comment: Good point; this is one case where I don't think there is a difference between quoting `$@` and not quoting it as well.

Comment: On 4.3.11(1)-release, `f() { local IFS=; a=${@:2}; echo "$a"; }; f a b c d` yields `bcd`, whereas `f() { local IFS=; a="${@:2}"; echo "$a"; }; f a b c d` yields `b c d` (as expected)…

Answer (score 1):

`[` is just (more or less) an alias for `test`, so you should use it like a regular command. What I want to say is, that you need whitespaces before and after `[` like this:

```
if [ $i -gt 1 ]; then
```

Also you forgot the `$` before `i` in the `if` clause.

Comment: Should really quote variable when using `[]` or alternatively just use `[[]]` as it is bash.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use $i as an index into your command arguments.  That won't work.  $i is the actual argument itself.  Use `shift` to discard the first argument and move all the others one place to the left.  Then you can just do `msg="$@"

Comment: I think OP also don't know how to assign variable. About `$msg=""`  :)

Comment: Nope ive litteraly coded in sh in 5 minutes :) Got it to work now, thx anyway

Comment: @Prototype  From bash manual page: **A variable may be assigned to by a statement of the form:** `name=[value]`. So assign variable should without dollar.  ;)

Comment: Unless the arguments being passed in are literally something like `1 2 3 4 5`, this approach won't work. `$i` is the *argument,* not the index. Though, admittedly, that's an issue with the OP's question as well.